# Disable Console logging in log4j2 web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j2

We have web application and using jetty maven plug-in in development environment. Created Log4j2.xml with all  application related logging, but when we run jetty server then it is showing all hibernate and spring logging by default in console.

How to disable console logging?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration status="error">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">[%d] %-5p %c{2} - %l %m %n</Property>
        <Property name="CONSOLE_PATTERN">[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>

        <!-- File Appender -->
        <File name="FileAppender" fileName="application.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </File>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Following sample with Console Appender

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration status="error">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">[%d] %-5p %c{2} - %l %m %n</Property>
        <Property name="CONSOLE_PATTERN">[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="CONSOLE_PATTERN"/>
        </Console>

        <!-- File Appender -->
        <File name="FileAppender" fileName="application.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="OFF">
<!--            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>-->
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```